# err (150) - trouble designing basic relational database

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to design a database for a little project I am working on in PHP. I don't have much experience working with databases (as you will soon notice) so right now I've thrown myself a little in the deep end.

I'm developing a database that will be the foundation for a basic stats system I am writing in PHP. I have concluded that I will need (at least) 3 tables.

`TOURNAMENT` - > **One tournament has many matches**

```
tournamentID SMALLINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
```

`MATCH` -> **One match has many players**

```
tournamentID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
matchID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
```

`PLAYER` -> **One player has many matches and many tournaments**

```
tournamentID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
matchID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
playerID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
```

My attempt to create this database:

```
<?php
//Connect
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("stats") or die(mysql_error());

//Drop old tables
mysql_query('DROP TABLE PLAYERS');
mysql_query('DROP TABLE MATCHES');
mysql_query('DROP TABLE TOURNAMENT');
echo('Old tables dropped<br \>');

//Create new tables

// TOURNAMENT
mysql_query('CREATE TABLE TOURNAMENT(
tournamentID SMALLINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, 
)') or die(mysql_error());
echo('TOURNAMENT created...<br />');

// MATCHES
mysql_query('CREATE TABLE MATCHES(
    tournamentID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    matchID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,

    PRIMARY KEY (tournamentID, matchID),
    FOREIGN KEY (tournamentID) REFERENCES TOURNAMENT(tournamentID)
)') or die(mysql_error());
echo('MATCH created...<br />');

// PLAYERS
mysql_query('CREATE TABLE PLAYERS(
    tournamentID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    matchID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    playerID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,

    PRIMARY KEY (tournamentID, matchID),
    FOREIGN KEY (tournamentID) REFERENCES TOURNAMENT(tournamentID),
    FOREIGN KEY (matchID) REFERENCES MATCHES(matchID)
)') or die(mysql_error());
echo('PLAYERS created...<br />');

echo('Blank tables created');

mysql_close();
```

When I execute the PHP script I receive err 150, which I think has something to do with my primary keys/foreign key references in the PLAYERS table:

```
Old tables dropped
TOURNAMENT created...
MATCH created...
Can't create table 'stats.players' (errno: 150)
```

I have done some reading and looked at some previous questions but I don't really understand the actual problem (the reason the error is occurring) in the first place. Clearly the design of my database is incorrect but I'm not sure how I should approach improving and fixing it.

Please help.

Comment: What is the exact error you recieve?

Comment: Can't create table 'stats.players' (errno: 150)

Comment: That isn't too helpful, is it...   Attempt to create the players table _without_ the primary key defined on tournamentID/matchID.  Normally err150 relates to data type mismatches between the FK column and the key it references.

Comment: Why is the primary key of the players table not 'playerID'? Maybe define the table with only two or three fields (including the PK) and get this right, then add the remaining fields.

Comment: Oh, also you might need an index on `matches.matchID` separate from the composite PK it has.  `UNIQUE KEY (matchID)`

Comment: You can also try removing the foreign key constraints, too, just to check that it's those that are causing the issue.

Comment: Ignore the comment I posted about 4-5 minutes ago, I just realized I had made a big mistake in it, will be double checking what I did. Sorry!

Comment: Your table definition for Tournament is empty .. did you leave it out on purpose?

Comment: Your table design is wrong. The 'tournaments' table should consist of an id, a name and a winner (which should be a team id, not a name). The 'matches' table should have an id (pk), tournament id (fk), team 1 id (fk), team 2 id (fk), score 1, score 2 (fk). The 'teams' table should have an id (pk) and a name. Presumably each team has several players and a player can only belong to one team, so then you need a 'players' table which should have an id (pk), name and team (fk). All the statistics belong in a new table whose primary key would be a composite of 'player' and 'match'.

Comment: @No'am Newman, I have purposefully omitted a teams table as player teams can erratically change between different tournaments, and on top of that, there is no easy way to determine players teams or the winner of a tournament from the data I am using, only the score of any given match. The `winner` column was actually to be manually entered by the user and I had no intentions to link it to anything in the database except the tournamentID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring any problems with table definition that people are commenting on above, the reason you're getting error 150 is because `Players` (obviously the table with the problem) can't be created because it can't use `matchID` as a foreign key.  Why?  Because you can only use foreign keys that are a key on the other table.

`PRIMARY KEY (one, two)` does make a unique primary key from these two columns, but only `one` will be considered a key on its own.

You can fix this easily by adding this to `Matches`:

```
...
PRIMARY KEY (tournamentID, matchID),
KEY (matchID),
...
```

Comment: This does technically fix my problem, so I guess it is the answer I was looking for! On the other hand, I now realize that I probably need to rethink the table deisgn. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: @anditpainsme at least you will know how to handle this error with your future design.